# Logging in C++: How do you produce separate log files for different objects and their children?

Tags: c++, logging

This is more of a design question: I have a number of "Jobs" and each job needs to have its own "Logger". A logger has a state (logging level, output location, etc.).
While processing a Job, I call functions from other objects that need to log information. Is there a better way to achieve this besides passing down a pointer to the logger all the way, as I have done in the code below?

If the logger was stateless a singleton instance could prevent passing down the instance.

Another idea could be to pass down a "JobID" and then use that to direct the logs to the right logger. but I wonder if there is a better design to avoid passing an extra argument.

```
    struct Logger{
        bool active;
        std::string id;
        Logger (bool shouldLog, const std::string& jobId /*or out file name etc.*/){
            active = shouldLog;
            id = jobId;
        }
        
        void log(const std::string& msg){
            if (active){
                cout << id << ": " << msg <<  std::endl;
            }
        }
    };
    
    struct A {
        A (Logger* logger) {
            logger->log("A");
        }
    };
    
    struct B {
        B (Logger* logger) {
            logger->log("B");
            A a(logger);
        }
    };
    
    struct Job {
        Logger * logger;
        Job (bool shouldLog, const std::string& jobId) {
            logger = new Logger(shouldLog,jobId);
        }
        
        void run()
        {
            std::thread job_child ( 
                [&] {
                    B b(logger); // b is created in a different thread
                });
    
            job_child.join ();
        }
        
        ~Job () {
            delete logger;
        }
    };
    
    int main()
    {
        Job j1(true,"j1");  // job might be created in a different thread
        std::thread job1 (
            [&] {
                Job j2(false,"j2");
                j2.run();
                j1.run();  // running the job in a different thread
            });
        std::thread job2 (
            [] {
                Job j3(true,"j3");
                j3.run ();
            });
    
        job1.join ();
        job2.join ();
                              
        return 0;
    }
```

Kudos to @Manuel for writing a working example. My goal is to avoid passing the logger pointer around.

Comment: Often, large interdependent systems like this pass around a context object, which includes all the specific information an instance needs.  In your case that could include a specific logger.  I like doing it via a context object a lot more than I do making the logger have to interpret IDs.  Alternately, you could have your logging object be a singleton that knows how to multiplex the logs from many different clients.

Comment: Do you have to write your own logging class? There are so many c++ loggers available.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53, thanks for replying that's very interesting. Does it mean that the context object is always passed as an argument?

Comment: @Nader Yeah that's one way to do it.  Have the global broker who's creating all of these instances pass along the appropriate context.

Comment: @drescherjm, the logger writes the logs into a DB and also produces some custom reports. Regardless even if I use another logger, the question is do I still pass it as an argument all the way down the function calls, or is there a better way.

Comment: Please post a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: If your jobs are threads, then you can get the logger based on the thread id or something similar: `Logger::GetInstance(std::this_thread::get_id())->log(whatever);` and you don't need to pass anything to anyone.

Comment: @Manuel . Thats a great idea and I was hoping to find a solution along those lines. Unfortunately, each job is processed in multiple threads (different queues) and also some of the functions that are called later on are multithreaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many threads as you want. You need only to link new threads with the parent.

I've added some utility functions to change logger for specific objects.

```
struct Logger {
    static std::map<std::thread::id, std::ofstream> _loggers;
    static std::map<std::thread::id, std::thread::id> _childs;
};

std::map<std::thread::id, std::ofstream> Logger::_loggers;
std::map<std::thread::id, std::thread::id> Logger::_childs;

struct JobScope {
    JobScope () {
        std::stringstream stream;
        id = std::this_thread::get_id();
        stream << id;
        std::cout << "Creating logger " << stream.str() << ".log" << std::endl;
        Logger::_childs[id] = id;
        Logger::_loggers[id].open (stream.str() + ".log", std::ios_base::out);
        Logger::_loggers[id] << stream.str() << ".log" << std::endl;
    }
    JobScope (std::thread::id old_id) : is_child (true) {
        id = std::this_thread::get_id();
        Logger::_childs[id] = old_id;
    }
    ~JobScope () {
        if (!is_child
            and Logger::_loggers[Logger::_childs[std::this_thread::get_id()]].is_open())
        {
            Logger::_loggers[Logger::_childs[std::this_thread::get_id()]].close ();
        }
    }
    void set_thread (std::thread::id pid) {
        Logger::_childs[id] = pid;
    }

    std::thread::id id;
    bool is_child {false};
};

struct JobScopes {
    static std::map<std::string, JobScope> _job_scopes;
    static JobScope & get_scope (const std::string & name) {
        return JobScopes::_job_scopes[name];
    }
};

std::map<std::string, JobScope> JobScopes::_job_scopes;

struct JobA {
    JobA (int pi) : i (pi) {
        Logger::_loggers[Logger::_childs[std::this_thread::get_id()]]
            << "Logger '" << Logger::_childs[std::this_thread::get_id()]
            << "': This is in A " << i << std::endl;
    }
    void run () {
        uint16_t c {0};
        while (c++ < 5) {
            std::cout << "A c=" << c << std::endl;
            Logger::_loggers[Logger::_childs[std::this_thread::get_id()]]
                << "This is in A " << i << " loop "
                << c << " "
                << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now())
                << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }
    int i {0};
};

struct JobB {
    JobB (int pi) : i (pi) {
        Logger::_loggers[Logger::_childs[std::this_thread::get_id()]]
            << "Logger '" << Logger::_childs[std::this_thread::get_id()]
            << "': This is in B " << i << std::endl;
    }
    void run () {
        uint16_t c {0};
        while (c++ < 5) {
            std::cout << "B c=" << c << std::endl;
            Logger::_loggers[Logger::_childs[std::this_thread::get_id()]]
                << "This is in B " << i << " loop "
                << c << " "
                << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now())
                << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }
    int i {0};
};

template<typename T>
std::thread create_thread (const std::string & name, T & job) {
    return std::thread(
        [&] {
            JobScope j (JobScopes::get_scope(name).id);
            job.run ();
        });
}

template<typename T>
void change_scope_and_run (const std::string & name, T & job) {
    JobScope scope_changer (JobScopes::get_scope(name).id);
    job.run ();
}


int main()
{
    JobScope & master = JobScopes::get_scope("main");
    JobA main_a (0);
    
    std::thread job1 (
        [&] {
            JobScope & j = JobScopes::get_scope("j1");
            std::thread job_child (
                [&] {
                    JobScope j (JobScopes::get_scope("j1").id);
                    JobA a (2);
                    JobB b (3);
                    change_scope_and_run<JobA>("main", a);
                    // this 'main_a' gets its own logger
                    change_scope_and_run<JobA>("other", main_a);
                    change_scope_and_run<JobB>("j1", b);
                });
            JobA a (1);
            // this time 'main_a' has 'main' logger
            change_scope_and_run<JobA>("main", main_a);
            // run on this thread
            change_scope_and_run<JobA>("j1", a);
            job_child.join ();
        });
    std::thread job2 (
        [&] {
            JobB b (2);
            // runs in this thread but logger "main"
            change_scope_and_run<JobA>("main", main_a);
            // run on this thread but logger "j2"
            change_scope_and_run<JobB>("j2", b);
        });

    job1.join ();
    job2.join ();
                          
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
manuel@desktop:~/projects$ for e in $(ls 13*); do echo -e "\nFile: $e"; cat $e; done

File: 139710164064000.log
139710164064000.log
This is in A 0 loop 1 1609168378
This is in A 0 loop 2 1609168379
This is in A 0 loop 3 1609168380
This is in A 0 loop 4 1609168381
This is in A 0 loop 5 1609168382

File: 139710172456704.log
139710172456704.log
This is in B 2 loop 1 1609168378
This is in B 2 loop 2 1609168379
This is in B 2 loop 3 1609168380
This is in B 2 loop 4 1609168381
This is in B 2 loop 5 1609168382

File: 139710180849408.log
139710180849408.log
Logger '139710180849408': This is in A 1
Logger '139710180849408': This is in A 2
Logger '139710180849408': This is in B 3
This is in A 1 loop 1 1609168378
This is in A 1 loop 2 1609168379
This is in A 1 loop 3 1609168380
This is in A 1 loop 4 1609168381
This is in A 1 loop 5 1609168382
This is in B 3 loop 1 1609168383
This is in B 3 loop 2 1609168384
This is in B 3 loop 3 1609168385
This is in B 3 loop 4 1609168386
This is in B 3 loop 5 1609168387

File: 139710180853568.log
139710180853568.log
Logger '139710180853568': This is in A 0
This is in A 0 loop 1 1609168373
This is in A 0 loop 1 1609168373
This is in A 2 loop 1 1609168373
This is in A 0 loop 2 1609168374
This is in A 0 loop 2 1609168374
This is in A 0 loop 2 1609168374
This is in A 2 loop 2 1609168374
This is in A 0 loop 3 1609168375
This is in A 0 loop 3 1609168375
This is in A 0 loop 3 1609168375
This is in A 2 loop 3 1609168375
This is in A 2 loop 4 1609168376
This is in A 2 loop 4 1609168376
This is in A 0 loop 4 1609168376
This is in A 2 loop 4 1609168376
This is in A 0 loop 4 1609168376
This is in A 0 loop 4 1609168376
This is in A 2 loop 5 1609168377
This is in A 0 loop 5 1609168377
This is in A 0 loop 5 1609168377
This is in A 0 loop 5 1609168377
```

I've passed parameters to `A` and `B` only to have some understandable output.

You have to synchronize access to the loggers, though.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this.  I modified your code and updated the question to better reflect what I am looking for. I think a variation of what you suggested may work, but I am not sure if it is simpler/cleaner than passing the logger pointer.

Comment: I don't know if this is better that passing the logger around, but with this technique you don't have to modify the "normal" objects signatures (i.e. constructors.) I've updated the answer to show how to share loggers between threads.

Comment: Uh. You mean you want the job in `main` logging to the logger of `main` even if in another thread?

Comment: I've added a method to run an object with a logger from another thread. Again, it may be simpler to pass the logger through parameters, but at least you can choose now.